# Unity question: When attaching my custom camera script camera shakes when player starts to move fast

Tags: unity, c#, camera, movement

Here is my player code.

```
Rigidbody rb;

Vector3 currMovement;
public float jumpSpeed = 10;
public float moveSpeed = 10;
public float rotSpeed = 180;

float distToGround;

public float smoothTimePos = 0.25f;
float currPos;
float targetPos;
float posVel;

public float smoothTimeRot = 0.25f;
float currRot;
float targetRot;
float rotVel;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    distToGround = GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.extents.y;
}

bool isGrounded() { return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, distToGround + 0.1f); }

void Update()
{
    targetRot = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * rotSpeed * Time.smoothDeltaTime;
    targetPos = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * moveSpeed;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    Move();
}

void Move()
{
    if (isGrounded())
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            rb.velocity += Vector3.up * jumpSpeed;
    }

    // Rotation smoothing.
    if (targetRot > 360)
        targetRot -= 360;
    if (targetRot < 0)
        targetRot += 360;
    currRot = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(currRot, targetRot, ref rotVel, smoothTimeRot);

    transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0, currRot, 0);

    // Movement smoothing.
    currPos = Mathf.SmoothDamp(currPos, targetPos, ref posVel, smoothTimePos);
    currMovement = new Vector3(0, 0, currPos);
    currMovement = transform.rotation * currMovement;

    rb.position += currMovement * Time.smoothDeltaTime;
}
```

I have a Rigidbody attached to my player. I think the problem is with my camera script. Here is my camera script.

```
public Rigidbody player;
Quaternion targetLook;
Vector3 targetMove, targetMoveRaycast, targetMoveUse;
public float smoothLook = 8, smoothMove = 0.25f;
public float distFromPlayer = 5, heightFromPlayer = 3;
Vector3 moveVel;

void LateUpdate()
{
    CameraMove();
}

void CameraMove()
{
    targetMove = player.position + (player.rotation * new Vector3(0, heightFromPlayer, -distFromPlayer));

    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(player.position, targetMove - player.position, out hit, Vector3.Distance(player.position, transform.position)))
    {
        targetMoveRaycast = hit.point;
        targetMoveUse = targetMoveRaycast;
    }
    else
    {
        targetMoveUse = targetMove;
    }

    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetMoveUse, ref moveVel, smoothMove);

    targetLook = Quaternion.LookRotation(player.position - transform.position);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetLook, smoothLook * Time.smoothDeltaTime);
}
```

The player is not an parent of my camera. When I parent the player to my camera the shake stops. But I want a custom smooth camera movement with my custom scirpt, so I can't make the player a parent of the camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Add a kinematic Rigidbody to the camera
2. Cache the rigidbody
3. Use rigidbody.position and rigidbody.rotation instead of transform.position and transform.rotation
4. Call CameraMove() from FixedUpdate() instead of LateUpdate()
5. Play around with interpolation on the camera and the player if necessary

   ```
   public Rigidbody player;

   Quaternion targetLook;
   Vector3 targetMove, targetMoveRaycast, targetMoveUse;
   public float smoothLook = 8, smoothMove = 0.25f;
   public float distFromPlayer = 5, heightFromPlayer = 3;
   Vector3 moveVel;

   private Rigidbody m_Rigidbody; // added

   /// added
   void Awake() {
       m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
       m_Rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
   }

   void FixedUpdate() { //Edited
       CameraMove();
   }

   void CameraMove() {
       targetMove = player.position + (player.rotation * new Vector3(0, heightFromPlayer, -distFromPlayer));

       RaycastHit hit;
       if (Physics.Raycast(player.position, targetMove - player.position, out hit, Vector3.Distance(player.position, m_Rigidbody.position))) {//Edited
           targetMoveRaycast = hit.point;
           targetMoveUse = targetMoveRaycast;
       }
       else {
           targetMoveUse = targetMove;
       }

       m_Rigidbody.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(m_Rigidbody.position, targetMoveUse, ref moveVel, smoothMove); //Edited

       targetLook = Quaternion.LookRotation(player.position - m_Rigidbody.position); //Edited
       m_Rigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(m_Rigidbody.rotation, targetLook, smoothLook * Time.smoothDeltaTime); //Edited
   }
   ```

Comment: Eyyyy body you helped me SO MUCH, BIG respect to you dude.